# Drop duplicates, but keep rows with highest value including ties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I want to drop duplicate values for `col1`, saving only rows with the highest value in `col2`. Example df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                   'col2': [5, 5, 10, 15, 20]})
```

I know `df1.drop_duplicates` will get rid of duplicate values, but how do I ensure that it is the highest value that is saved (or multiple values if there are values tied for highest)?

Desired output:

```
dfoutput = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                       'col2': [5, 5, 15, 20]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by sorting your DataFrame in descending order. Next, compute two masks, one for figuring out what rows are the maximum in their group, and the other to figure out what rows are duplicated.

We can then combine these masks to determine what rows are duplicated *and* not the maximum in their respective groups, and perform one final filtering step.

```
v = df1.sort_values('col2', ascending=False)
m1 = v['col2'] == v.groupby('col1', sort=False)['col2'].transform('max')
m2 = v.duplicated('col1')

v[~(m2 & ~m1)].sort_index()   # v[~m2 | m1] - DeMorgan's Law

  col1  col2
0    a     5
1    a     5
3    b    15
4    c    20
```

Comment: I like the first one better, it gives the output that the OP wished for. :)

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks! Didn't realise there was a discrepancy in the result! +1'd yours as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) function of Pandas:

Assign the rank to each row of the group. If the values are same, rows will have same rank. Something like below:

```
In [126]: df1['rnk'] = df1.groupby('col1')['col2'].rank()
In [127]: df1
Out[127]: 
  col1  col2  rnk
0    a     5  1.5
1    a     5  1.5
2    b    10  1.0
3    b    15  2.0
4    c    20  1.0
```

Then use [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method to filter only ranks less than `2.0`:

```
In [129]: df1.query('rnk < 2.0').drop('rnk',1)
Out[129]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     5
1    a     5
2    b    10
4    c    20
```

#### Can combine both the above commands to get a 1-line solution:

```
In [130]: df1[df1.groupby('col1')['col2'].rank() < 2]
Out[130]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     5
1    a     5
2    b    10
4    c    20
```

Comment: Interesting solution!

Comment: Actually, there is no need for the extra column, just doing `df1[df1.groupby('col1')['col2'].rank() < 2]` will work.

Comment: Yes, I know there's no need of the extra column. Just put it there for the understanding of OP.

Answer (score 2):

another way which I found :

get duplicates and append it with deduplicated values after sorting in  `decending` order , then get rid of the duplicated index.

```
dfoutput = df1[df1.duplicated(keep=False)].append(df1.sort_values(['col1','col2'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['col1']))
dfoutput[~dfoutput.index.duplicated()].sort_index()

    col1    col2
0   a       5
1   a       5
3   b       15
4   c       20
```